# How to store login info of a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, authentication

I have an application developed in WPF. I would like to add Login page which will be system specific. Multiple User can registered in the machine with the application. I would like to know the best approach , local db to store credentials or service which will validate the credentials. If it is local DB please suggest appropriate one which is tiny, secured and compatible with .net application.

Answer (score 1):

It will actually depend on how you want to set it up or achieve it.

I would actually use Microsoft SQL Server Management DB to achieve this. You can use System.Data.SqlClient Class in your WPF application to store and retrieve User login information from the DB. I would do this in following steps:

- Step 1: Make a DB in Microsoft SQL Server Management
- Step 2: Create a    Table to store User login Credential with
  different Data fields along    with their data types, which will vary
  based on what credentials you    want the user to be verified.
- Step 3: Create a login page as per your    requirement
- Step 4: Use System.Data.SqlClient class options in your    login page
  to be able to connect, retrieve or save data of user login
  credentials in the DB.
- Step 5: While saving the user credentials in    DB use Microsoft's own
  Hash secure class or Encryption class to save    the data in DB (without saving the password as raw in the DB Table).
- Step 6: Use the same Encryption class to verify the    credentials
  after retrieving the hashed/encrypted credential from DB using SQLClient.

This is a general walk through or logic of building a User login Credential Page in WPF application but this may vary based on your software requirement or how you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a database, there is a simplier solution. You can store data in User.cfg. Here's how:

Step 1: Add an entry in the application’s resource dictionary.

```
<Application x:Class=”SampleApp.App”
   xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation”
   xmlns:x=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml”
   xmlns:properties=”clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties”
   Exit=”OnExit”
   StartupUri=”MainWindow.xaml”>
     <Application.Resources>
         <properties:Settings x:Key=”Settings” />
     </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Step 2: Use the setting.

```
<TextBox Text=”{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Username}” />
```

Step 3: Save the setting.

```
private void OnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Access the setting:

`Properties.Settings.Default[“Username”]`

For more information, follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25829/User-Settings-Applied).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLite` as a local database of your project. All your data is stored in one single file on your hard disk. You can install `SQLite` through NuGet package manager.